# Installing shoutpy / Boost.python on windows

Tags: python, boost, windows-7, mingw

I have tried to install ShoutPY (http://dingoskidneys.com/shoutpy/) under python 2.7 x86 on windows but install fails with:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install shoutpy
Searching for shoutpy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/shoutpy/
Reading http://dingoskidneys.com/shoutpy/
Best match: shoutpy 1.0.0
Downloading http://dingoskidneys.com/shoutpy/shoutpy-1.0.0.tar.gz
Processing shoutpy-1.0.0.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\vladim~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-pnwegl\shoutpy-1.0.0\s
etup.cfg
Running shoutpy-1.0.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\vladim~1\appdata
\local\temp\easy_install-pnwegl\shoutpy-1.0.0\egg-dist-tmp-otdtxq
shoutpy.cc:26:28: fatal error: boost/python.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What I figured out is that I am missing Boost.python. Tried to find how to install it but failed, could anyone help me out?

thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/) is not sufficient?

Comment: What is your OS? Seems to be the fact that you only need to install Boost -library. Use apt-get to do it for instance.

Comment: @Masi it's Windows 7, found solutions for linux but I can't find anything for Win...

Comment: belongs to superuser imo

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not running this under Cygwin, so you have a couple challenges. Did you install `gcc`? It's required by your install. You'll also need Boost installed and as Bart said in the comments, the best thing to do is to check out their [build/install documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/building.html).

Comment: I have gcc and am using mingw for all "console" needs. Currently building boost with python, but still not sure where to put those libraries once I'm done with building.

Comment: I haven't used mingw, but my guess would be /usr/lib/, /lib/ or in your python site-packages directory depending upon what is being built. Really surprised the install doesn't move them for you...